# Print matplotlib title just above a table extract form a Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a data frame that can change size depending on the input.
I plot this data frame in the form of a table using matplotlib.
Here's my code :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

the_table = ax.table(cellText=df_to_plot.values, colLabels=df_to_plot.columns, loc='center')
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)  # To have a correct display
the_table.set_fontsize(7)
ax.set_title(f"{title}\n", y=1, pad=10)
fig.tight_layout() # I tried with and without
fig.savefig(save_name, bbox_inches='tight') # save_name end with .pdf
```

My problem appears when i have a dataframe with many rows, the title overlaps the table.
I tried to put `y=1` to print the title a the top of the fig but it stills overlaps.
I tried to set a `pad` but it doesn't change anything.
I tried to use `.thight_layout()` to correct it but it throws a error : *UserWarning: Tight layout not applied.*

My table does not exceed the pdf file but there is no place at the top for the title.[image: Result of the matplotlib plot with the title overlaping]

I want the title to be just above my table, regardless of its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `bbox` parameter gives you best control over placing the [table](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.table.html?highlight=table#matplotlib.axes.Axes.table):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(88,7)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(210/25.4, 297/25.4), layout='constrained')
fig.suptitle('The Title')
ax.axis('off')
table = ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, bbox=[0,0,1,1])
table.set_fontsize(7)
fig.savefig('table.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: To have a good result I removed the `layout='constrained'`. I also change : `figsize=(len(df_to_plot.columns), (len(df_to_plot.index)/250)+1)` To have someting dynamic.